# Data provided in Nevada State Plane NAD83 Modified Ground in US Survey Feet - what projection to us in QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I have data provided in "Nevada State Plane NAD83 Modified Ground in US Survey Feet"  ... what projection do I use in QGIS to display this correctly.  When I try the various West Nevada projections in QGIS the information end up in the ocean west of Africa.  An example of coordinates provided that should plot ~7 miles ESE of Yerington Nevada is 1,525,000 (Y) 361,000 (X).

Answer (score 1):

If you go to http://epsg.io you can search for projections. If you search for ["Nevada NAD83"](https://epsg.io/?q=Nevada%20NAD83%20) there are 4 pages of possibilities about half of which are in US ft.

The easiest way to be sure is to ask the person who sent you the data to include the `.prj` file or tell you the EPSG code. Otherwise pick the zone closest to where your data is for and do a test reprojection until you find the correct one.